# update order status after order creation

Tags: 6, ubercart

i try to update status like this

```
function module_order($op, &$arg1, $arg2) {
  switch ($op) {
      case 'update':
      $money = 'Cash';
      if (isset($arg1->custompane) && $arg1->custompane == $money) $arg1->order_status = 'completed';
      break;
    }
}
```

It does not work.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `order_save()` should be used after modifying the order.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional actions to achieve this. Conditional actions are part of Ubercart.